# can't connect to any server : 111 connection refused (curl, apt etc.), ping and nslookup work

Tags: networking

I am running Ubuntu in windows 10. I know, I know, I'm sorry. This is not my personal computer, and I am trying to do this to avoid using a virtual machine as this is more ram efficient. Anyway, I am having a hard time diagnosing the problem as no other solutions I have found seem to mean anything in this case.

```
irh@MM212767-PC:~$ wget google.com
--2018-06-08 13:18:34--  http://google.com/
Resolving google.com (google.com)... 172.217.8.14, 2607:f8b0:4004:803::200e
Connecting to google.com (google.com)|172.217.8.14|:80... failed: Resource temporarily unavailable.
Connecting to google.com (google.com)|2607:f8b0:4004:803::200e|:80... failed: Network is unreachable.
ihoover@MM212767-PC:~$ ping google.com
PING google.com (172.217.8.14) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from iad23s59-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.8.14): icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=14.4 ms
64 bytes from iad23s59-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.8.14): icmp_seq=2 ttl=52 time=13.9 ms
64 bytes from iad23s59-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.8.14): icmp_seq=3 ttl=52 time=16.8 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 13.984/15.111/16.880/1.266 ms
irh@MM212767-PC:~$ curl google.com
curl: (7) Failed to connect to google.com port 80: Connection refused
irh@MM212767-PC:~$ sudo apt update
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.149). - connect (111: Connection refused) [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Err:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
  Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152). - connect (111: Connection refused) [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.149). - connect (111: Connection refused) [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/InRelease  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/InRelease  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/InRelease  Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152). - connect (111: Connection refused) [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Thank you for your help!

Edit: Had to set up Ubuntu to access the correct corporate proxy server. Now things are running correctly.

Comment: Is this a work computer?  It looks like what's happening is there's  something on the network blocking your access (Firewall, perhaps, on the border of the network) that prevents you from going directly outbound to the Internet.  You might end up having to talk to whomever actually *owns* the computer or network to fix the problem.  (There's probably a web gateway you have to configure to route traffic through, possibly)

Comment: That very well could be. It is a work computer. Since from W10 I have unrestricted internet access, I assumed the windows subsystem for Linux would as well. Thanks, I'll try to see if I can get help from IT.

Comment: *"From W10 I have unrestricted internet access":* have you tried running the same `wget` command in Windows? You can get a native Win32 `wget` from [eternallybored.com](https://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/), for example.

Comment: @AlexP I doubt they have "unrestricted internet access", my guess is there's a proxy server or web content gateway at play somewhere.  And since the OP doesn't actually *own* the computer they wouldn't be able to install (or possibly even run) those other binaries.

Comment: @ThomasWard: My experience is that if they have enough privileges to browse the internet with a regular browser they will also be able to download a zip file, and extract and run an executable. Usually organizations which forbid the latter also forbid the former, especially nowadays with Gmail, Gapps, Dropbox, Evernote and other such dangerous services.

Comment: @AlexP Except on Windows you can **force** all Internet traffic over a proxy, whether that proxy or system actually *restricts* traffic or not is a different issue, many companies run things such that all web traffic has to flow through a web gateway or such for content access control, so whether they can access the Internet unrestricted from their Windows computer *because it's directly going out to the Internet rather than passing through a proxy or web gateway first* is beyond the ability for end-users to really determine, and when you get IT teams involved really.

Comment: @AlexP Further, OP doesn't own the computer in question, so they really should be checking with IT first before using things like WSL (which might be against their policies and rules for how to use computers on their networks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You indicate in comments that this is a work computer.  I'll bet you that **there is a firewall and an Access Control List in place to control how systems access the Internet** at the border of the network.

Many companies have a restriction in place about how you can go out to the Internet, which includes a policy to control the types of sites you can access, and many companies have specific web gateways or proxies which control data access.

Since you don't actually *control* the computer, or the network, you need to talk to the IT teams at your work to determine how to properly access the Internet from your device via WSL.  I would be ready to expect some push back though, because many IT teams don't want you to be running things you shouldn't be (my guess is WSL falls into this category), or without their authorization/review.